# Pure CSS Loading indicator fit to container size

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I want to use the following loading indicator for containers while data is being loaded.
The problem is, that the slider has a fixed width and height (300px & 300px), but I want it to fit dynamically into a container. When I try to add width: 140px; and height: 140px; to the main-container class the loading indicator looks awful and the proportions are not correct.

**EDIT by Rickard**
I added a slider and border so it's easier to see what's going wrong.

```js
let sliderElement = document.getElementById("slider");
let mainContainerDiv = document.querySelector(".main-container");

sliderElement.oninput = function() {
  changeContainerSize(this.value);
}

function changeContainerSize(value) {
  mainContainerDiv.style.width = value + "px";
  mainContainerDiv.style.height = value + "px";
}

changeContainerSize(sliderElement.value);
```

```css
.main-container {
  border: 1px solid; /* for demo purpose :: Rickard */
}
.reverse-spinner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #1976d2;
  border-left-color: #1976d2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}
.reverse-spinner::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  content: "";
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #03a9f4;
  border-left-color: #03a9f4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spinBack 1s linear infinite;
  animation: spinBack 1s linear infinite;
}

.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox > div {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 2px dashed green; /* for demo purpose :: Rickard */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

-webkit-@keyframes spin {
  -webkit-from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  -webkit-to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinBack {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-720deg);
    transform: rotate(-720deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinBack {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-720deg);
    transform: rotate(-720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" min="100" max="500" value="500">

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div>
      <div class="reverse-spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the code of the spinner like below to rely on percentage values and on the padding trick to maintain the ratio then you can easily adjust the dimension by changing only the width:

```css
.reverse-spinner {
  width: 100px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #1976d2;
  border-left-color: #1976d2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.reverse-spinner::before {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  padding-top:calc(70% - 8px);
  margin:15%;
  border: inherit;
  border-top-color: #03a9f4;
  border-left-color: #03a9f4;
  border-radius: inherit;
  animation: spin 0.5s linear infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="reverse-spinner"></div>


<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:80px;"></div>

<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:40px;"></div>

<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:40%;"></div>
```

Another version with less of code and without the use of `calc()`

```css
.reverse-spinner {
  width: 100px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,transparent 95%,#1976d2 96%) 
    top/100% 50% no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.reverse-spinner::before {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  padding-top:70%;
  margin:15%;
  background:
      radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,transparent 93%,#03a9f4 94%) 
      top/100% 50% no-repeat;
  border-radius: inherit;
  animation: spin 0.5s linear infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="reverse-spinner"></div>


<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:80px;"></div>

<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:40px;"></div>

<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:40%;"></div>
```

Another one still with less of code:

```css
.reverse-spinner {
  width: 100px;
  background: top/100% 50% no-repeat;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,transparent 95%,#1976d2 96% 99%,transparent 100%);
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.reverse-spinner::before {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
  background:inherit;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,transparent 73%,#03a9f4 74% 79%,transparent 80%);
  animation: spin 0.5s linear infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="reverse-spinner"></div>


<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:80px;"></div>

<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:50px;"></div>

<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:40%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can make a loader using SVG. In which to set `viewBox =" 0 0 140 140 "`
Wrap the `div` loader and set the width of the parent container as a percentage.

In the example below,  uses the same `id = "loader"` loader in three containers
`<div class = "reverse-spinner">` with dimensions: `width: 10%`, `width: 20%`, `width: 30%`

```css
.reverse-spinner {
display: inline-block;
}
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh; 
background:#EAEAEA;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
     <!-- Container width:10% -->
<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:10%; background-color:gold; " >
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 140 140"  >  
 <g id="loader" >
    <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="60" fill="none" stroke="#1976D2" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="188.4" stroke-linecap="round" >
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" values="0;376.8" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>   
   <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="40" fill="none" stroke="#03A9F4" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="125.5" stroke-linecap="round" >
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="1s" values="251.2;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>
  </g> 
</svg> 
</div> 
         <!-- Container width:20% -->
<div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:20%; background:#31C1B0;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 140 140"  >  
     <use xlink:href="#loader" > </use> 
  </svg> 
</div>  
            <!-- Container width:30% -->
  <div class="reverse-spinner" style="width:30%; background:#FFA6E3;">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 140 140"  >  
       <use xlink:href="#loader" > </use> 
</svg> 
</div> 
</div>
```

This example uses `input` to dynamically change the width of the parent container:

```css
.container {
width: var(--w1,40px); 
background:#EAEAEA;
 
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="range" min="40" max="600" oninput="document.querySelector('.container').style.setProperty('--w1', this.value + 'px');" value="50"><span>width Container</span><br> 
</div>
<div class="container" >

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 140 140" style="border:1px solid;" >  
 <g id="loader" >
<circle cx="70" cy="70" r="60" fill="none" stroke="#1976D2" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="188.4" stroke-linecap="round" >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" values="0;376.8" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>   
   <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="40" fill="none" stroke="#03A9F4" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="125.5" stroke-linecap="round" >
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="1s" values="251.2;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>
  </g> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Added another example with text wrapping around the parent container.

This example further demonstrates the adaptability of filling a parent container with an SVG application.

```css
.container {
width: var(--w1,60px); 
background:#EAEAEA;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 1em;
}
.txt {
font-size:1.2em;

}
```

```html
<div class="cont" >
<input type="range" min="60" max="600" oninput="document.querySelector('.container').style.setProperty('--w1', this.value + 'px');" value="60">
</div>
<div class="container" >
<svg  viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <circle class="maskCircle" cx="60" cy="60" r="40" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="8" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="251.2">
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="3s" values="251.2;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  </mask>
</defs>
    <circle class="background" cx="60" cy="60" r="40" fill="none" stroke="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="8" />
  <circle class="default" cx="60" cy="60" r="40" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="8"
  stroke-dasharray="3.14" stroke-dashoffset="40"  mask="url(#msk1)">
  
  </circle>
</svg>
</div> 
<div class="txt">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec vehicula est non nunc ultricies, sit amet pharetra nulla congue. Vestibulum hendrerit ante ac rhoncus aliquet. Quisque vitae est turpis. Nulla sit amet felis nec nisl blandit mollis.

Nullam ornare turpis quis orci hendrerit, vitae varius est tincidunt. In quis malesuada tellus. Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. Integer congue facilisis enim porta pretium. Morbi scelerisque tincidunt purus, vitae rhoncus tortor tristique nec. Nullam laoreet turpis nec felis vehicula finibus.

Fusce ultricies maximus ante vitae imperdiet. Proin magna orci, pretium nec pretium id, ultricies in risus. Praesent mauris ipsum, semper nec convallis sit amet, vestibulum non enim. Quisque volutpat nulla ac nulla venenatis, ac cursus nulla laoreet. Aliquam malesuada dui a orci tristique tristique. Phasellus fringilla, velit eget ultrices efficitur, justo lacus elementum lorem, nec convallis augue lacus non dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris sagittis, sapien in tristique mollis, ex libero laoreet magna, ut pellentesque dolor augue accumsan elit. Nunc ut augue at eros sollicitudin malesuada. Pellentesque urna felis, posuere sit amet odio et, vestibulum aliquet ex. Nulla eu dolor blandit, bibendum nibh in, tincidunt ex. Ut nisl justo, tincidunt a augue et, gravida sollicitudin neque. Donec id dignissim elit, a sollicitudin leo. Aliquam placerat orci justo, et faucibus nibh volutpat vel.

Nulla varius, est eu dictum vulputate, risus tellus euismod augue, ac tempus velit elit nec dui. Duis eleifend metus eu nisi mattis scelerisque. Proin finibus neque ut pellentesque porta. Etiam quis ligula non ligula sollicitudin efficitur at a turpis. Morbi tristique maximus quam eu imperdiet. Morbi dolor augue, sagittis non urna quis, fringilla scelerisque erat. Praesent et tempor tortor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ut consectetur arcu, id vestibulum sapien. Integer in metus et lacus sollicitudin sollicitudin. Curabitur vulputate mollis odio, sit amet dictum mauris condimentum non. Vestibulum enim risus, luctus a tristique sit amet, semper non enim. Nunc laoreet hendrerit massa at blandit.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris dapibus eu ipsum ac semper. Suspendisse turpis nunc, mattis sit amet lorem id, fringilla iaculis purus. Praesent egestas est id ullamcorper tristique. Nulla tempus sem rutrum, sagittis dui quis, condimentum massa. Nam efficitur purus sed sapien euismod imperdiet. Donec laoreet augue eget justo dapibus suscipit. Etiam eleifend neque iaculis, pellentesque elit vel, malesuada justo. Aenean efficitur eros quis mattis convallis. Quisque hendrerit libero ligula, vel fermentum orci ultrices vel. In porttitor congue interdum. Duis ac vehicula est. Nullam sollicitudin eros a tortor semper, laoreet facilisis neque hendrerit. Integer faucibus elementum nibh, id venenatis urna consectetur a.
</div>
```

Comment: I would consider a scale transformation in order to keep both circles the same: https://jsfiddle.net/d9cvfeo1/. easier to adjust if we don't know a lot of SVG calculation

Comment: @Temani Afif I understood your idea. Take two identical circles and reduce one inside svg. I downloaded your file but unfortunately it doesn’t work in either `Chrome` or` Firefox`  In my solution, the absolute values of the radii of circles without transformation were used and this is a more reliable solution.  I do not specify the width and height of the SVG, leaving only the `viewBox`, which forces the SVG application
fully occupy the parent container (gray square)
When resizing the parent container, svg resizes proportionally.

Comment: @TemaniAfif You will probably agree with me that the more approaches with CSS and SVG to solving one problem the better